# Implement `advanced cloud events selectors` for aws cloudtrail via terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

Is there some way by which I can implement custom **Advanced data events selector** for cloud trail via terraform. Stuck on this for quite some time now. This is what I want to achieve via terraform.
[image: .]

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do this?

Comment: Yea got it. You were right. Did it via `local-exec` provisioner using AWS CLI 2 sdk. Thanks a lot buddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its **not yet supported** in terraform. You would have to set it up using `local-exec` yourself with aws-cli.